# SLIM FRAMEWORK 3: Can't pass variable from middleware to controller

Tags: php, middleware, slim-3

What's wrong with my code? I can't pass variable from my Auth middleware to controller. In controller, the attribute "null".

Index:

```
$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$api = new \Slim\App($c);

$api->group('/', function () use ($api) {
$this->post('login', '\AuthController:login');
...
$this->post('getIngredientsCategories', '\IngredientsController:getIngredientsCategories');


})->add(new ApiAuthenticateController());

$api->run();
```

Middleware (ApiAuthenticateController)

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class ApiAuthenticateController
{
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
{
    $jwtDecoded = null;
    $req = $request->getUri()->getPath();
    $_req = RequestValidatorController::isRequestEnabled($req);

    if ($_req !== false) {
        if ($_req['login_required']) {
            $jwt = filter_var($request->getHeaderLine('AUTHORIZATION'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $jwt = explode(" ", $jwt)[1];
            try {
                $jwtDecoded = JWT::decode($jwt, JWT_SECRET, array('HS256'));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $this->deny_access($response);
            }
        }
        $request = $request->withAttribute('foo', $jwtDecoded);
        //HERE - attribute "foo" in $request exists - checked by var_dump()..
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        return $response;

    } else {
        return $this->deny_access($response);
    }
}
```

IngredientsController

```
class IngredientsController extends Controller
{
  private $_ingredients;

  public function __construct(\Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container)
  {
      parent::__construct($container);
  }
}
```

Controller

```
class Controller
{
  private $request;
  private $response;
  protected $data;
  protected $method;
  protected $user;

  public function __construct(Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container)
  {
     $this->request = $container->get('request');
     $this->response = $container->get('response');
     $this->data = (object)Tools::stripInput($this->request->getParsedBody());
     $this->method = $this->request->getUri()->getPath();
     $this->user = $this->request->getAttribute('foo');
     var_dump($this->user);
     // returns NULL. if $this->request->getAttributes()... returns empty
 }
}
```

Please note, that code is "cleaned" for this post and for better readability, some functions and conditions where deleted. Code is working - sorry for possible typos.

Comment: the problem is simple, you are returning the response, instead of passing it to the next response handler, you should accept the answer below ;)

Comment: I changed it but problem wasn't solved and the result is without change...as I commented below

Answer (score 3):

the problem is coming from here

in the middleware ApiAuthenticateController, you should change the code like this

```
$request = $request->withAttribute('foo', $jwtDecoded);
// you should return the $next here not to do anything else
return $next($request, $response);
```

and in your IngredientsController:getIngredientsCategories part of code you should return the

```
function getIngredientsCategories ($request, $response, $args){

    //do your job...
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return $response;

}
```

and finally, in the constructor, you have don't have the actual $request after the middleware I think so you would have the $this->request->getAttributes() inside your getIngredientsCategories function

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Calling **$this->request->getAttributes()** inside my getIngredientsCategories function has no result. Only when I call **$request->getAttributes()** inside getIngredientsCategories function which is one of function params **($request, $response, $args)**. I need to access object user in all methods (+ many classes of project), so it would be better if could get this object (user) in my constructor and set it globally.

Comment: Headers are accessible in global Controller's constructor, but attributes not